# Can I use AJAX to load code from a different file/view/page so that I could do something similar to SPA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Long story short, I believe what I'm trying to do is very similar to a Single Page Application but on a really small scale. My goal is to make the admin panel of my website less cluttered with information by separating that information into tabs. The thing I imagine would look like this:

My admin panel:

```
<div class="admin-container">
    <ul>
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div>This empty div will be populated with the code from the loaded file </div>
</div>
```

The code which resides in a different file which I would like to load into the empty div when I click the first tab:

```
        @if(!empty($categories) && count($categories) > 0)
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('deleteCategories') }}">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <div class="categories-flexbox">
                    <img class='profile-picture' src='{{ url("storage/uploads/categories/thumbnails/".$category->image_file_name) }}' alt='Random image' />
                    <p>{{ $category->name }}</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{{ $category->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryFiles[]" value="{{ $category->image_file_name }}">
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <button class='delete-btn' type="submit">Delete</button>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('delete') }}
            </form>
        @endif
```

Obviously, this will not be the only file which would be used for loading. There's gonna be a respective file for tab 2 and tab 3. The admin panel page shouldn't refresh when I have clicked on any of the tabs, however, the content of the empty div should be changed to the code in the other page/view.

Is what I have described achievable using AJAX or should I look into other means? I have already used AJAX to insert and delete stuff into/from the database and then change the HTML on success, but this seems a tab more complex to do.

Comment: With JQuery `$('#mydiv').load('somepageurl',functin(){alert('loaded')})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something similar to this.

```js
function createTabComponent(wrapper){
        $wrapper = $(wrapper);
        $buttons = $wrapper.find('> ul > li');

        $divs = $wrapper.find('> div');
        $divs.hide();

        $urlsLoaded = $buttons.map(function(){ return false; });

        $wrapper.find('>ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            $buttons.removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $divs.hide();

            var index = $buttons.index($this[0]);
            $divs.eq(index).show();

            if(!$urlsLoaded[index]) {
              var url = $this.data('url');
              $.get({
                  url: '/' + url,
                  success: function(html){
                    $urlsLoaded[index] = true;
                    $divs.eq(index).html(html);
                  },
                  error: function(){
                    $urlsLoaded[index] = true;
                    $divs.eq(index).html('Error loading url: '+ url);
                  }
              });
            }
        
        });

        var activeTab = $buttons.filter('active');
        if(activeTab[0]){
            activeTab.trigger('click');
        }else{
            $buttons.eq(0).trigger('click');
        }
    }

    createTabComponent('.admin-container');
```

```css
  .active{
    background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="admin-container">
  <ul>
    <li data-url='file1Url'>Tab 1</li>
    <li data-url='file2Url'>Tab 2</li>
    <li data-url='file3Url'>Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can change the content of the tab with AJAX by sending the HTML content via the AJAX response. But in my opinion, it's much better to use a frontend framework/library like Vue to handle this.

You can also pre-render all the HTML but hide them, then using JS to conditionally change their visibility.